# SQL - Show Only Consecutive Rows That Meet Criteria

Tags: sql

Here is a sample database table. I want to write a SQL query that returns a table that shows all the data but filters out cars that never have an E for status (So A1 below should not show up in the results), filters out cars that have less than 4 consecutive occurrences of Es (So A2 below should not show up because although it has 4 different Es, they are not consecutive). So only A3 should show up in the results. Ideally, I'd like to see the complete history of A3. So it should give me the rows with trip_order 1 through 7 even though some have Ls. But this is not necessary, I can live with just showing me all the consecutive Es rows (trips 3 through 6). I don't know if this is possible with a GROUP BY function because I don't want to mess up the order of the rows. I don't want to just know which cars have at least 4 Es in their history. I want to see which ones are consecutive Es based on trip_history order.

```
CAR_NUMBER   |    STATUS    | TRIP_ORDER
-------------+--------------+------------
A1           |     L        |  1
A1           |     L        |  2
A2           |     L        |  1
A2           |     E        |  2
A2           |     E        |  3
A2           |     E        |  4
A2           |     L        |  5
A2           |     E        |  6
A3           |     L        |  1
A3           |     L        |  2
A3           |     E        |  3
A3           |     E        |  4
A3           |     E        |  5
A3           |     E        |  6
A3           |     L        |  7
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions to count occurrences where four Es occur in a row (based on `trip_number()`):

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when lag4e = 4 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by car_number) as car_has_4es
      from (select t.*,
                   sum(case when status = 'E' then 1 else 0 end) over
                       (partition by car_number 
                        order by row_number
                        rows between 3 preceding and current_row
                       ) as lag_4e
            from t
           ) t
      ) t
where car_has_4es > 0;
```